# Link on a row and link on an anchor inside a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with entries and each row of the table is clickable (when you click the row, it goes to a details page). Everything is ok except the fact that if I put an anchor on the same row, it will try to go to anchor's URL and immediately after it will redirect to the row's attached link.

How can I prevent the row action using jQuery?

```
<tr class="clickable-row" ...>
    <td><a href="..."></a></td>
</tr>

$('.clickable-row').click(function () {
        document.location = "...";
});
```

Comment: Can u pls show your code ?

Comment: I updated my question. Please check again.

Comment: Please share your code, and a http://jsfiddle.net/ would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **[stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**(); to stop the default action

```
$("a").click(function(e){

e.stopPropagation();

// do ur work
});
```

> **Description:** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this if this is according to your requirements.

```
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

for more details:
[Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0?rq=1)